# How To Show Full Directory Name On Task Bar For Grouped Directories on Windows 10

Tags: windows, user-interface, operating-system

I am using Windows 10 and frequently have a lot of directories open at once. I have always been annoyed that the directory names, when you hover on the task bar, do not show the full path. Since many of my clients have directories called *docs* it becomes a bit of a challenge to go searching. I was wondering how to show the full directory on hover.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured this out. I felt fairly stupid once I solved it, and for anyone out there that is hung up on this issue and not having a lot of luck Googling.

1. Launch Any File Explorer window.
2. Click The View option at the top left.
3. Next click the options button.
4. Open the "View" tab.
5. Finally check the box that shows "Display the full path in the title
   bar" and then click "apply" & *ok* (NOTE: You can also click apply to all folders)

The only caveat is that it does make your user interface a bit more cluttered but once you get use to it, it is not that bad.

Here are some images I put together to hopefully help someone like me that is stuck on this simple task:

Default Taskbar Stacked View:

[image: My Toolbar Initial Stack Problem]

Open Any File Explorer Window:

[image]

Options Dialog:

[image]